# With Broken Laptop Monitor and Good External Monitor on Toshiba With Windows 8.1, How to get past boot difficulties?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, external-display, toshiba-laptop

I have listed my parameters in the title.  Something is wrong with the boot process, I never get to the point where my external monitor is used.  I tried this awesome blind navigation sequence which I found elsewhere

1. Boot windows to safe mode (just in case, wait 4-5min after turning laptop/desktop on)
2. Press Win+R
3. Type msconfig and press enter (wait like 30 sec just to be sure)
4. Press right keyboard arrow 5 times
5. Press tab 3 times
6. Press space key
7. Press tab 8 times
8. Press enter
9. Press tab
10. Press enter

which does appear to restart my laptop, but it ends up stuck in the same state it started in.  I also have tried fn+F4 which is proper for my keyboard and I have tried WIN+P+P as well as I saw that mentioned somewhere on the web.

Is there any other way that I can potentially get past this or at least see a log somewhere that describes why my computer refuses to boot up all of the sudden?

Comment: Just as an aside, the above combination really did not do anything special for my setup.  It just coincidentally happened to reset my machine from the repair screen,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the laptop (then the display will only be sent to the external monitor).

Use a USB keyboard and mouse to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try this evening and then report back

Comment: Yes, I am able to debug doing that method.  Now my computer is trying to automatically repairing itself and failing so I have the long task ahead of figuring out how my computer got corrupted.